# stack, linked list template errors

Tags: c++

There are 2 errors in my code.

First, 2 errors on stackWritemirror function in **listrec.cpp**

1. void Stack  :: push (const SE &): Can not convert 
      argument 1 from ListNode  * to const SE &.
2. Can not convert from '=' SE to ListNode  *.`

Here is my code.

Headers are not included.

**listrec.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "listrec.h"
#include "stacklnk.cpp"

template<class LE>
void List<LE>::stackWriteMirror() const
{
    Stack<ListNode<LE*>> tempstack;
    ListNode<LE> *a;
    a = head;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        tempstack.push(a);
        a = a->next;
    }
    while (!tempstack.empty())
    {
        a = tempstack.pop();
        std::cout << a->element;

        a = a->next;
    }
}
```

**stacklnk.cpp**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "stacklnk.h"
template < class SE >
void Stack<SE>::push(const SE &newElement)
{

}
template < class SE >
SE Stack<SE>::pop()
{

}
```

Need help fix these errors.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: i want to print backwards using stack.

Comment: You need to provide full source code including header file. Without the definition of 
 your custom Stack, List classes, we cannot debugging it. Also, it would be appreciated that which line is suffered by error.

Answer (score 0):

First error is because, apparently, you are pushing ListNode typed variable into tempstack, not the ListNode.

Second error comes from the type problem in First error. If you change the type of variable `a` with `ListNode<LE>*` to `ListNode<LE*>`, it will be fixed.

I think you need to study more about defining variables in c++, c.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class LE>
void List<LE>::stackWriteMirror() const
{
    Stack<ListNode<LE*>> tempstack;
    ListNode<LE*> a; // first error edited
    a = head;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        tempstack.push(a);
        a = a->next;
    }
    while (!tempstack.empty())
    {
        a = tempstack.pop(); // Second error comes from this line, I expect?
        std::cout << a->element;

        a = a->next;
    }
}
```